# Crontab on Mac OSX

Tags: osx, cron

I have created an /etc/crontab file on a Mac OS X that runs a few simple commands. I would like to use the crontab to echo a statement in my terminal, logout from the OS (as if I was to point my mouse to the command Logout), and I am trying to test it by running an echo statement every two minutes. Here is what I have so far:

```
55 12 * * * echo "Don't forget to log out!! Will be automatically logging out at 12PM Sharpe!!"
* 13 * * * logout
1 * * * * echo "Test"
```

At that point, I used `crontab /etc/crontab` to ensure that my user points to the crontab file (which it does) and was able to confirm it by typing `crontab -l`.. What will i need to do in order to make it so that it echoes in my terminal and have it actually Log out of the operating system at 12 Noon everyday?

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: I am using El Capitan

Comment: Where would you expect to see the output? The commands are being run in a separate subshell that has nothing to do with what you're actually running yourself. I suggest you post a new question explaining what you are trying to achieve. Your cron is doing precisely what you told it to do, it's just that you told it to do the wrong thing :)

Comment: I was actually expecting to see the output in the terminal I am in... But if it is echoing somewhere else, I suppose that's fine. Just as long as it logouts exactly at noon every day, that is what I am concerned about..

Comment: It will log out every day.. of the subshell that's running the cron job.  It will not log out a user who is currently logged in by any means.

Comment: Ok I am going to update my question...

Comment: As @terdon implied, this may be an A B Question issue.  What is it that you're trying to accomplish that has led you to think that `cron` is the answer?

Comment: @DopeGhoti, i updated my question in hopes to clarify. FYI I have logout aliased to osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to log out'"

Comment: Alias definitions are usually not in place in `cron`s environment, as they are handled by the login shell (usually `bash`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actual intent is to force a logout of the active user of the system at 1300 every day, try this in the `root` user's crontab:

```
0 13 * * * osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to log out'
```

If you don't wish to display a confirmation dialog to the user, you can use:

```
0 13 * * * osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to  «event aevtrlgo»'
```

Answer (score 1):

The cron table entries *are* running.  They don't run on your active terminal; they run on their own.  If your host has a local mail daemon running, you can see the output of the cron jobs which have output (e. g. the `echo` jobs) in emails sent to your local account by the local mail daemon.

Comment: Do you mean in /var/mail/<user>? I don't see anything in there that indicates the echo statement has run..

Comment: If `/var/mail/<user>` is empty, it's already been delivered.  Try running `mail` in the Terminal. (not to be confused with `/Applications/Mail.app`)

Answer (score 1):

The use of `cron` in OS X has been strongly discouraged for a while now in favor of their "better" option called `launchd`.  There are numerous tutorials on how to run jobs with `launchd` but just to get you started here's one.

http://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-startup-crontab-launchd-jobs